# RTClib library the second, second

Tags: arduino-uno, library, rtc

I'm using [RTClib](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib) for my DS3231 module, the problem is the library is displaying the second without zero behind it: `22:1:1` and when i print the time on my 16x2 LCD time is displaying like this:

> 22:22:59
>
> 22:23:19
>
> 22:23:29
>
> ...
>
> 22:23:59
>
> 22:23:10
>
> 22:23:11

the second number of seconds is not getting cleared.
i know one solution to this is to use `lcd.clear()` function to update the LCD in each loop but is there any other way to clear that second number or do something so library show zero behind second?

Comment: What do leap seconds have to do with anything?

Comment: @Majenko sorry there was a misunderstanding, updated the question.

Comment: Your problem is that you are printing 1. People don't do that for time. You use 01.

Comment: how to use "01"? is there a setting i have to change?

Comment: If the seconds are less than ten, then print a 0. Then print the seconds. It's that simple. The library has nothing to do with it. It's what you do with the number in your code that matters.

Comment: if you please post that as an aswer i'll pick it as correct answer. `lcd.print(now.second());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your responsibility to format the time properly, not the library. The library just gives you a number. If you want a leading zero then it's up to you to provide that leading zero.

For example:

```
if (now.seconds() < 10) {
    lcd.print("0");
}
lcd.print(now.seconds());
```

Or:

```
char timestr[9];
snprintf(timestr, 9, "%02d:%02d:%02d", now.hours(), now.seconds(), now.minutes());
lcd.print(timestr);
```

Comment: what's `snprintf`? it's giving me this error: `expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token`

Comment: @newbie: It's [a very standard libc function](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#ga77070c245d4ca4f7ec7d7144260fb875).

Comment: @EdgarBonet i'm sorry but what's the error is about?

Comment: Did you use the code *inside a function* or just dump it into global scope?

Comment: i'm guilty of dumping it inside the global scope... i know i'm being a headache right now but can you please explain a bit more? @Majenko

Comment: Put it in loop() where you want to display the time.

Comment: @Majenko  thank you.